# Power BI connection with excel and update the BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I am using excel to compile media industry data and then get into the Power BI Desktop through the normal procedure. After incorporating additional/ incremental information in the excel sheet then I have to refresh the Power BI Desktop so that my visualization could retain the latest info.
I have very huge data in MS Excel sheet, there are almost 700,000 rows and around 15 fields.

When I add only just 2 rows in Excel sheet then every time I have to refresh the Power BI Desktop so that I could see the impact of new data. It takes usually sometimes and effects the efficiency.

Can anyone please guide the efficient solution of this issue?

Regards,

Jamal Qamar

Answer (score 1):

Save the Excel file using Excel binary format (.xlsb). The file size is much reduced and many operations are accordingly faster.